# No Instance of type variable R exist so that Observable conforms to Observable?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-android

I am new in Rx android.When i try to call

```
Observable.from(imagesMulty).map(image -> printImage(image)).subscribe();
public  void printImage(Image image)
    {
Subscription addImage;  


addImage = retrofit.create(Restapi.class).addImage(image)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<Response<SlideResponse>>() {
                    @Override
                    public final void onCompleted() {
                        dismissProgress();

                }

                @Override
                public final void onError(Throwable e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                    dismissProgress();

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Response<SlideResponse> apiResponse) {
                    dismissProgress();
                    if (apiResponse.code() == 201) {


                    }

                }


            });
    subscriptions.add(addSlide);
    }
```

its showing No Instance of type variable R exist so that Observable conforms to Observable.Let me know whats is this error and how to resolve.My requirement is make api call one after other.

i tried to add compile "com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0" also but still error exist.

Answer (score 0):

`RxJava2` doesn't allow you to use `Observable.from()` function. Use are using `com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0` with `RxJava`. (Version confliction)

Best implementation should be like this (in `Rxjava2`)

```
Disposable subscription;
subscription = Observable.just(imagesMulty)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Consumer<String>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(@NonNull String s) throws Exception {
                    // do retrofit stuff
                }
            }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(@NonNull Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                    throwable.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
subscription.dispose(); // Call in onDestroy() or onPause()
```

If you want to combine or zip your retrofit stuff with `map` operator, consider using [zip](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html), [concat](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/concat.html) or [combinelatest](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html) ...

Answer (score -1):

you can try this example. This may help to solve your problem
https://github.com/dustin-graham/RxAndroid-Sample